# Is there evidence to suggest that Captain Lorca and Garth of Izar are the same person?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery, captain-lorca

In the Star Trek Original Series episode [S3:E16](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Whom_Gods_Destroy_(episode)) *Those Whom the Gods Destroy* - we meet a character named [Garth of Izar](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Garth_of_Izar).

[image]

We know the following about him:

> Garth of Izar was a decorated, highly regarded officer in the Federation Starfleet and former starship captain, who rose to rank of fleet captain in the course of his service through the mid-23rd century. His career dissolved in a dramatic descent into madness and attempted genocide, resulting in his commitment to the Elba II asylum for the criminally insane.

We also know that he was one of [Kirk's](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/James_T._Kirk) heroes - until Kirk finally meets him.

We know that Brian Fuller [said the following](http://www.startrek.com/article/bryan-fuller-reveals-discovery-details) of Star Trek Discovery's place in the timeline:

> There's an incident, an event, in the history of Starfleet that has been talked about (in previous Star Trek shows), but never fully explored.

This hints at some unspoken backstory prior to TOS.

In Star Trek Discovery [S1:E3](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Context_Is_for_Kings_(episode)) *Context is for Kings* - we see that [Captain Lorca](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Gabriel_Lorca) has some sort of trophy room of weapons. We also see several incidents where the [Admiral Cornwell](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Katrina_Cornwell) pulls Lorca up for his behaviour, as if she things he is losing control.

[image]

What if the "incident" involves the [Battle of Axanar](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_of_Axanar), and Lorca ends up being Garth of Izar?

My question is:**Is there evidence to suggest that Captain Lorca and Garth of Izar are the same person?**

Comment: I dearly hope so.

Comment: Albeit the question is fairly interesting, we have seen the same episodes of ST:D as you. If you want on screen evidence to support your theories, and you haven't found anything yourself, other people can't really be of much help.

Comment: While very interesting this isn't really a question. You already present the evidence in the "question".

Comment: Thanks @Giles that’s helpful. My understanding is that the rules of this site require you to do some prior research before asking a question. I humbly present what I have found in the hope that people more informed than me can better answer the question.

Comment: related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174387/is-there-evidence-to-suggest-that-admiral-cornwell-and-lethe-are-the-same-person?rq=1 - there is an episode of Disco named "Lethe" - which is also the name of a character from the Garth episode

Comment: @NKCampbell But "Lethe" is a reference to the mythological Greek river which would wash away your memories - the character in "Dagger of the Mind" had had her memories/personality wiped with Dr Adams' neural neutralizer, and TOS was *big* on symbolism like that.  (Also why the telepathic "Letheans" are so called, with their ability to attack people's minds)

Comment: oh you are right @Chronocidal - I stated that Lethe was in 'Whom Gods Destroy' and that is incorrect. Given the events of S1 - it seems like the question is irrelevant now but yeah - oops on my part!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruled out by events leading up to the season finale. We learn that

> The Lorca we've been watching all this time turned out to be an "infiltrator"/"imposter" from an alternate universe (TOS "Mirror Mirror").